# Handling when a user asks the same question N times instead of editing

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users

What should happen to the questions in a situation where a user creates an account, asks a question, and then re-asks the same basic question with input from the previous answers (often asking for clarification)? Later [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203187/qaedus) drops out for a while, no answer selected, no question resolved.

I'm assuming the questions should get closed or deleted leaving the most recent one. Is this best achieved through flagging or closing as duplicate, or is my assumption wrong?

I feel like it's a bit of a failure in perceiving the differences here from a forum, and learning to edit, and even delete one's own question.

Note: If this has been asked before I couldn't find it, so hopefully not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one question has most of the useful answers, and the others have very few to no good answers, then vote to close them, or flag them for moderator attention.

If multiple questions have good answers in each one, flag them for moderator attention, and ask that they be merged, listing the relevant questions.

Also, add comments to each one pointing people to the correct/latest/most complete one, and additional comments to the OP suggesting how they can edit their question rather than starting a new one.

Comment: The odd thing is that for some reason I had your careers page open.

Comment: I detected that and only decided to answer this question because I knew you had it open.  I've posted my careers page as an example to several careers meta questions, so it was probably open for that.

Comment: I like the former explanation.