# Exact Duplicate question by same user

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've taken a look at the related questions [Handling when a user asks the same question N times instead of editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29539/handling-when-a-user-asks-the-same-question-n-times-instead-of-editing), [User keeps asking essentially the same question but not exact duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90304/user-keeps-asking-essentially-the-same-question-but-not-exact-duplicate), etc. This case seems slightly different.

A user has asked the same question twice with slightly different wording, but there is absolutely no extra information. The newer question clearly says:

> Sorry for the duplicate question as I am not getting any reply.

How do we handle this case? The user seems fairly well-established (>500 rep). Do we just mark as dupe or is there a specific mod request? Do you see an opportunity to educate?

Here are the questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948195/unable-to-make-a-call-to-http-put-and-delete-is-not-working-method-not-allowed
- [405 Method Not Allowed PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926126/405-method-not-allowed-put)

Comment: OMG they were both asked *today*? Talk about impatient `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake Less than a day apart, yep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag or vote to close the exact duplicate as a duplicate of the first question, and explain to the user that posting the exact same question about the exact same problem *is not allowed*, and that if he or she hasn't gotten an answer yet, then he or she may try improving their question by adding more information or clarifying it, or adding a bounty.

If the user continues to repeat this repeatedly thereafter, then flag one of the user's posts for moderation attention using the Other option, and explain that the situation. The moderator might choose to temporarily suspend the user for "failing to learn" how to use the site properly.

As stated in [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/):

> When users exhibit a pattern of...
>
> #### No effort to learn and improve over time
>
> - This user does not put reasonable effort into the questions they ask of the community.
> - There is little or no evidence of this user learning over time, either in the topic itself or in the community norms on the site.
> - This user intentionally spams the site with the same question or very similar questions, over and over.
> - The user never gives anything back to the community, but only takes.
>
> … these problem behaviors have to be dealt with.

One tool used to deal with this kind of problem behavior is a suspension.